# Using MongoDB to separate different user data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm already familiar that MongoDB is based on documents that are in JSON format. I'm creating my first web app using the MEAN stack, where users can register and then be able to sign in to a back-end dashboard where they can implement products/profile information etc. How would I set that up to be stored on MongoDB? would each user be stored as a document? And as far as security reasons, how can I go about not allowing a GET request to be able to get a different users information?

Currently, I just have a collection of users, and a collection of products (with the unique id number for each user), etc. to me that doesn't seem the proper way to store data.

If anyone can help me on how to setup the database for Mongo that would be fantastic! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> would each user be stored as a document?

Yes, each user is an *object*, thus it's stored as a separate *document*.

> how can I go about not allowing a GET request to be able to get a different users information?

This has nothing to do with Mongo or any other data storage mechanism. You'll need to work on a Web service layer which exposes your data filtering requests to authorize them based on user role, claims or any authorization approach you might find useful in your scenario.

Maybe you should look at implementing [OAuth2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). There's a package that integrates with Express to implement your own [OAuth2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authorization server: [node-oauth2-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oauth2-server).

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, I just have a collection of users, and a collection of
>   products (with the unique id number for each user), etc. to me that
>   doesn't seem the proper way to store data.

You are on the right way actually. Now when you show products page for users you need to retrieve only documents that belong to that single user that is currently authenticated, this implies that you have authentication set up, and products have a `userId` field.

This is how most application work. If you want to read about other ways of solving this then read about [multi-tenancy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx).